# Quadratic equation problem solving

Tags: functions

Below are two functions. These functions were both originally the same function $f(x)$ but were transformed using the constant 'p' by either $f(x)+p, f(x+p), p \cdot f(x)$ or $f(p \cdot x) $
If p=3 what was the original function.

Function 1: $3x^2+-12x+-15$

Function 2: $x^2+2x+-8$

Comment: You will find it somewhat more illuminating to "complete the square" for each of these quadratic functions.  It will be clearer what sort of shifts, stretches, etc. were made .

Comment: @Indy  
See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic tutorial on MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

Let the original function be $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$
$f(x)+p = ax^2+bx+c+3$
$f(x+p)=a(x+3)^2+b(x+3)+c=a(x^2+9+6x)+bx+3b+c=ax^2+(6a+b)x+(9a+3b+c)$
$pf(x)=3ax^2+3bx+3c$
$f(p.x)=9ax^2+3bx+c$
In $f_1$ and $f_2$, the ratio of coefficient of $x^2$ is $3:1$. The coefficients of $x$ are different. There isn't an obvious relation between the constants.  The functions that seem to match these criterion are $f(x+p)\text{ and }pf(x)$.

$3x^2-12x-15=3ax^2+3bx+3c$
$a=1,b=-4,c=-5$
So the function is $\boxed{x^2-4x-5}$
Putting these in $ax^2+(6a+b)x+(9a+3b+c)$,
$x^2+2x-8 = f_2$
Thus, we have verified that our function is correct.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this is simply testing for each of the four possible transformations by reversing them and looking for similarities - a relatively "guaranteed" method to solve this problem. However, plainly by looking, we might be able to quickly recognize that Function 1 looks like the third transformation $p \cdot f(x)$ and that Function 2 looks more like either the first or the second transformation.

To "de-transform" Function 1, which, as guessed equals $p \cdot f(x)$, we divide the function by $p$ to retrieve $f(x)$: $f(x) = \frac{3x^2 - 12x - 15} 3 = x^2 - 4x - 5$.

Taking what we assume to be $f(x)$ given from above, we can try to guess the transformation applied to Function 2 to verify. The first transformation doesn't work because $f(x) + p$ in this case clearly doesn't equal Function 2 ($x^2 - 4x - 5 + 3 = x^2 - 4x - 2 \neq x^2 + 2x - 8$). So we try the second transformation, $f(x + p)$: $(x+3)^2 - 4(x+3) - 5 = (x^2 + 6x + 9) - (4x + 12) - 5 = x^2 + 2x - 8$ - therefore, not too surprisingly, we verify that

$$f(x) = x^2 - 4x - 5$$